# Auto start google translate on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the google translate widget on my website. I want to change it so it auto starts the translation for only one specified language on page load. No language dropdown to be shown. Here is my current widget code. Thanks.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'de,es,fr,nl', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have an english site, but when someone visits the page I want it to show everything in french without the user toggling the language dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

I generated the code in the google translator site. Follow the code below

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'de,es,fr,nl,pt', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript"  src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I had not really tested, when I tested didn't worked. So I generated the code again and this time it worked. You need to change the autoDisplay property to `false`. If not work, you can go to google and generate the code, because, the meta tag is generated automatically for each website.

Comment: Thanks but I already have this exact code as in my question above. I want to change it so it auto starts the translation for only one specified language on page load. No language dropdown to be shown.

Comment: @user1823053 You changed the layout parameter?